# Vlookup in R referencing columns and rows

Tags: r, merge, data.table, vlookup

I would like help with replicating a vlookup from Excel in R. I have two data tables of the following kind but with several more rows and attributes. I have redimensioned them for the sake of simplicity -

```
FX <- data.table(Currency = c("USD","EUR","AUD"), Y2014 = c(2.13,3.45,1.8), Y2015 = c(2.16,3.48,1.7), Y2016 = c(2.19,3.49,1.6))

DATA <- data.table(Customer = c("Abc","Def","Ghi","Jkl","Mno"), Year = c(2013,2014,2015,2012,2018), CurrencyCode = c("AUD","USD","USD","EUR","USD"))
```

**FX** has a list of currencies as the rows and different years as columns denoting their exchange rate against a fixed currency (SEK) and **DATA** has some customer deals which were originally reported in that fixed currency (SEK).

I would like to add another attribute to **DATA** called, as an example, **ConversionRate** by first matching the **Currency** attribute in **FX** to **CurrencyCode** in **DATA** and then selecting the corresponding conversion rate for the year given in **Year** from **DATA** by matching it to the column **Yxxxx** in **FX**.

It would result in something like this -

```
data  <- data.table(Customer = c("Abc","Def","Ghi","Jkl","Mno"), Year = c(2013,2014,2015,2012,2018), ConversionRate = c(1.7,2.13,2.16,3.45,2.19))
```

Please note that for **Year** < 2014, I would like it to pick up the rate of the corresponding currency in 2014 and for **Year** > 2016, I would like it to pick up the rate of the corresponding currency in 2016 as it has done for Row 1,4,5.

I have tried using loops, merge, and even a custom vlookup function but it seems I am going wrong when it comes to comparing the **Year** to the column names **Yxxxx**.

Any idea on how this can be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After melting FX to long and converting the "Y2016" etc. values to numbers, you can do an update join to `DATA` with this fx_long. If you want to join on a year other than the year in the data, you can first create a new column `join_year` and join on that instead.

```
library(data.table)

fx_long <- melt(FX, 'Currency')[, Year := as.numeric(sub('Y', '', variable))]

DATA[, join_year := pmin(pmax(Year, 2014), 2016)]

DATA[fx_long, on = .(join_year = Year, CurrencyCode = Currency), ConversionRate := i.value]



DATA    
#    Customer Year CurrencyCode join_year ConversionRate
# 1:      Abc 2013          AUD      2014           1.80
# 2:      Def 2014          USD      2014           2.13
# 3:      Ghi 2015          USD      2015           2.16
# 4:      Jkl 2012          EUR      2014           3.45
# 5:      Mno 2018          USD      2016           2.19
```